# How to convert string to timespan ? visual basic, stopwatch, lap system

Tags: vb.net, timespan, stopwatch

I am a beginer and making a stopwatch with lap feature using visual studio 2012, visual basic. Now I stuck in the lap feature. In the lap feature I want to display the result using listview ...
When the user click the lap button 2nd times it has to show the lap time between first click and 2nd click.. but i m not getting the result. Is here anybody to resolve my problem ? thank u in advance 
here is the code of lap button event

```
Private Sub btnLap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLap.Click

    Dim lap As String = (sw.Elapsed.Hours.ToString("00") & ":" & sw.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString("00") & _
      ":" & sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString("00") & ":" & sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString("00"))

    lapcount += 1
    Dim i As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count
    If i <= 0 Then
        ListView1.Items.Add(CStr(lapcount), i)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(lap)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(lap)
    Else
        ListView1.Items.Add(CStr(lapcount), i)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(lap)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add((TimeSpan.parse(lap)- Timespan.parse(lastlap)).ToString) ''' I can't subtract the value from 2nd click to first click

    End If
    lastlap = (ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, don't create the `String` in that verbose manner. If you're using .NET 4.0 or later then just call `ToString` on your `TimeSpan` and provide a format specifier, e.g. `Dim lap = sw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")`.

Comment: As for your question, there's no need to convert a `String` to a `TimeSpan`.  The `String` you have came form a `TimeSpan` in the first place so just use that original value.  In your case, you could store that `TimeSpan` in the `Tag` of the `ListViewItem` and get it back from there when you need to use it.

Comment: That said, if you did need to convert from a `String` to a `TimeSpan` then you would call `TimeSpan.Parse` or `TimeSpan.Parseexact`.  You should know that already because you should have read the documentation for the `TimeSpan` structure before posting here.

Comment: By the way, if you are using .NET 3.5 or earlier then `TimeSpan.ToString` cannot custom format output. In that case, you could create a `DateTime` with that `TimeSpan` and form that, e.g. `Dim lap = (Date.Today + sw.Elapsed).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")`. That will only work if you can guarantee times of less than 24 hours.  I assume that's OK because your original code wouldn't handle longer periods anyway.

Comment: Mr. jmcilhinney, Thank you very much for commenting on this. I am using .NET 4.0. I searched for this for 2 days and got the info about TimeSpan.parse and applied but it dont work .. I m really not  getting that .. I tried this Dim lap = sw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff") but it still dont subtract the value. I stored the the variable lastlap = listview1.items(i).subitems(1) .tostring

Comment: when i use the original variable (lap - lastlap) , an error occur that says can't change to Double from String, and when I change to CDbl(lap) - CDbl(lastlap) still doesnt work . what should i do?

Comment: You should what I already said to do. There's no `Double` values being used here.  If you're trying to use `Double` values then you're doing it wrong.  How about you do what I said to do?  I told you to put the `TimeSpan` you have in the `Tag` of the `ListViewItem`. Have you done that?  If not, why not? I told you to get that `TimeSpan` back from the `Tag`. You can then simply subtract one `TimeSpan` from another to get the difference as another `TimeSpan`.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure if the standard subtraction operator has always been supported for `TimeSpan` values.  If not, there's a `Subtract` method.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, its usually a bad idea to use UI objects as your primary store of data. You would be much better storing the split times in a `List (Of TimeSpan)` and calculating calculating the lap times from that.

In my sample I declared some class objects so that the code would run. You could adapt these as necessary.

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch
Dim lapcount As Integer = 1
Dim lastlap As Integer
Dim lapintervals As New List(Of TimeSpan)
Dim timeFormat As String = "hh\:mm\:ss\.fff"
```

So in your button click event you would have something like this ..

```
Private Sub BtnLap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLap.Click
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = sw.Elapsed
    lapintervals.Add(ts)
    AddTimeToListView(lapintervals.Count, lapintervals.Last)
    lapcount += 1
End Sub
```

And you would add the info to your ListView like this

```
Private Sub AddTimeToListView(lapcount As Integer, lapsplit As TimeSpan)
    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem(lapcount.ToString, lapcount)
    If lapcount = 1 Then
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(lapsplit.ToString(timeFormat))
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(lapsplit.ToString(timeFormat))
    Else
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(lapsplit.ToString(timeFormat))
        lvItem.SubItems.Add((lapsplit.Subtract(lapintervals(lapcount - 2))).ToString(timeFormat))
    End If
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

thenk you very much for answering... 
finally i have finished my stopwatch application .. 
i've made this and my leader gave me 8 out of 10 .. it pretty much good for me 
here is the design form and code

[visual basic 2012, stopwatch with lap button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5FlF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S42JO.png)
[code]

Public Class Stopwatch
    Public watch As Form 'スタートページから呼び出すため
    Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()

```
Dim lapcount As Integer
Dim lastlap As String

'スタート・ストップボタン
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    If btnStart.Text = "Start" Then
        sw.Start()     '時間計測開始
        Timer1.Interval = 10
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        btnStart.Text = "Stop"

    Else
        sw.Stop()   '時間計測一時停止
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        btnStart.Text = "Start"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lblTime.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\:ff")

End Sub
'cancel / reset ボタン
Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    sw.Reset()     '初期状態にする
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    lblTime.Text = "00:00:00:00"
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    btnStart.Text = "Start"
    lapcount = 0

End Sub

'ラップボタン
Private Sub btnLap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLap.Click

    Dim lap = sw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\:fff") ' ラップ時間を変数に代入

    lapcount += 1
    Dim i As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count
    If i <= 0 Then                                       ' ＬｉｓｔｖｉｅｗのアイテムのＶａｌｕｅが０または０より小さければ
        ListView1.Items.Add(CStr(lapcount), i)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(lap)                 'アイテムとサブアイテム表示
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(lap)

    Else '文字列となっている結果時間を整数型に変換する/　// ラップ経過時間を取得するため
        Dim day As Integer = 0
        Dim hr As Integer = CInt(Strings.Left(lap, 2))
        Dim min As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lap, 4, 2))
        Dim sec As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lap, 7, 2))
        Dim milli As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lap, 10, 3))

        Dim dayy As Integer = 0
        Dim hrr As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lastlap, 19, 2))
        Dim minn As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lastlap, 22, 2))
        Dim secc As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lastlap, 25, 2))
        Dim millii As Integer = CInt(Strings.Mid(lastlap, 28, 3))

        '現在のラップ時間に直前に記憶したラップ時間を引き、1回目から2回目のラップボタン押下までの経過時間を図る
        Dim answer = createtimespan(day, hr, min, sec, milli) - createtimespan(dayy, hrr, minn, secc, millii)
        Dim ansTS = answer.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\:fff") 'ミリ秒3桁まで表示するように指定

        ListView1.Items.Add(CStr(lapcount), i)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(lap)
        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add((ansTS).ToString)  'ラップ時間の表示

    End If
    lastlap = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ToString   '直前のラップタイムを記憶
End Sub

Private Function createtimespan(ByVal days As Integer, ByVal hours As Integer, ByVal minutes As Integer, _
                                ByVal seconds As Integer, ByVal milliseconds As Integer) As TimeSpan

    Dim elapsedTime As New TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

    Return (elapsedTime)

End Function
```

End Class